# Obtener twits de un país específico usando paquete rtweet, su función lookup_coods() y la geocoding-API de google maps

Tags: google-maps, r, twitter, google-geocoding-api

He instalado rtweet y cuando quiero recolectar tweets de un país específico, diferente a los Estados Unidos, el paquete no recolecta ningún dato. Para ello he instalado la llave para las siguientes API´s de Google:
**geocoding API**, **Maps JavaScript API** y **Geolocation API**

¿Me pueden ayudar a revisar mi código o señalarme cómo se puede hacer esto?

Aquí están los pasos que seguí:

Generar un token de google

```
google_maps_token<-"my key XXXXXXXXXX"
```

Ruta al home directory

```
home_directory <- path.expand("~/")
```

Combinar con nombre del token

```
file_name <- file.path(home_directory, "google_maps_token.rds")
```

Guardar el token en el home directory

```
saveRDS(google_maps_token, file = file_name)
```

Crear una variable en el ambiente de R

```
cat(paste0("GOOGLE_MAPS_PAT=", file_name),
file = file.path(home_directory, ".Renviron"),
append = TRUE)
```

Visualizar la variable en el ambiente de R

```
usethis::edit_r_environ()
```

TWITTER_PAT=/Users/xxxx/.rtweet_token1.rds
GOOGLE_MAPS_PAT=/Users/xxxx//google_maps_token.rds

Después de guardar el token con la API key de google, reinicio RStudio y empiezo a recolectar tweets con rtweet y esto sucede:

load rtweet

```
library(rtweet)
```

tweets de Estados Unidos

```
 tweets_USA <- search_tweets("#lang:en",
                        geocode = lookup_coords("USA",apikey = "google_maps_token"),
                n=10, include_rts = FALSE)
```

Searching for tweets...
Finished collecting tweets!

[image: tweets Estados Unidos]

Tweets de México

```
tweets_Mexico <- search_tweets("#lang:es",
                           geocode = lookup_coords("mexico",apikey = "google_maps_token"),
                n=10, include_rts = FALSE)
```

Searching for tweets...
Finished collecting tweets!

[image: No se recolectan tweets de México]

Asimismo, cuando uso la función lookup_coords() para "USA" esta si funciona

Coordenadas de Estados Unidos
    usa <- lookup_coords("usa")

[image: coordenadas de Estados Unidos]

Pero cuando uso el nombre de otro país no se recolectan las coordenadas

Coordenadas de Brasil

```
bz <- lookup_coords("brazil")
```

[image: No se guardan coordenadas de Brasil]

¿Estoy cometiendo algún error en el código?

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Podrías verificar la `url` a la que termina accediendo `lookup_cord`, es algo así: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=###&Brazil"` dónde `###` es tu API_KEY? digo para descartar problemas con el token?

Answer (score 1):

@pmoracho ya encontré la falla. Para poder llamar a la variable con la llave guardada en el ambiente de R ("environment variable") hay que usar la función Sys.getenv() Escribo un pequeño ejemplo a partir de la pregunta inicial:

Generate a variable with the coordinates from Mexico

```
mexico_coord <- lookup_coords(address = "mexico",
                      components = "country:Mexico",
                      apikey=Sys.getenv("google_maps_token.rds"))
```

Después de esto puedo usar search_tweet() para recolectar 10 tweets de México en español

```
tuits_Mex_esp_10 <- search_tweets("lang:es",
                      geocode = mexico_coord, n = 10)
```